# Start Stop Daemon Init Debian - Unrecognized arguments

Tags: linux, bash, shell, uwsgi, init

This is my debian init script so far to start uwsgi in emperor mode:

```
cat <<EOF >/etc/init.d/uwsgi
#!/bin/bash
daemon="$APPVENV/bin/uwsgi"
args=( --emperor "$APPCONF/uwsgi/app.ini"
       --daemonize /var/log/emperor.log
       --emperor-pidfile "$APPDIR/emperor.pid" --gid \$(id -g "$APPUSER")
     )
pid="$APPDIR/emperor.pid"
case "\$1" in
    start)
        echo "Starting uwsgi"
        start-stop-daemon -m -p \$pid --start --exec \$daemon \$args
        ;;
    stop)
        echo "Stopping script uwsgi"
        start-stop-daemon --signal INT -p \$pid --stop \$daemon \$args
        ;;
    reload)
        echo "Reloading conf"
        kill -HUP \$(< \$pid)
        ;;
    *)
        echo "Usage: /etc/init.d/uwsgi {start|stop|reload}"
        exit 1
    ;;
esac
exit 0
EOF

chmod u+x /etc/init.d/uwsgi
update-rc.d uwsgi defaults
service uwsgi start
```

When I run this command I get this response:

```
> service uwsgi stop                                                                   
Stopping script uwsgi                                                                                 
start-stop-daemon: unrecognized option '--emperor'                                                    
Try 'start-stop-daemon --help' for more information.
```

However, I know `--emperor` is a perfectly valid argument of uwsgi. So what's going on, am I putting the uwsgi arguments in the wrong place?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I suspect you shouldn't be escaping all those `$` signs. Look at some of the other scripts that your system has for comparison... Also, you may need a `--` before your `$args`...

Comment: I left an error in my answer to one of your previous questions, involving how the `args` array should be used. Let me update that answer rather than answering here.

Comment: Actually, the problem appears to be that the value of `args` (which you should change from `\$args` to `"\${args[@]}"`, by the way) is being treated as arguments to `start-stop-daemon`, not arguments to `uwsgi`. I don't know enough about `start-stop-daemon` to know the correct solution, but I suspect twalberg's suggestion to use `--` is correct.